# TypeScript code similar to Revealing Module Pattern structure

Tags: javascript, typescript, revealing-module-pattern

I want to convert some JavaScript code I've written into TypeScript. I'm rather new to TypeScript syntax and way of thinking, as a JavaScript developer.

What is giving me a headache is the hard time I've had to convert some piece of code that uses the Revealing Module Pattern into TypeScript.

One example is the below:

```
//JS Code
var obj;

//code...
(function(){
    function myFunction(){
        //do work
    }


    function MyOtherConstructor(){
        return {
            publicMethod: myFunction
        }
    }

    obj = new MyOtherConstructor();
})();

//use obj.publicMethod in code later
```

One workaround I've thought was this:

```
//TypeScript code
var obj;

class MyOtherConstructor {
        private callback: any;
        constructor(f: any){
            this.callback = f;
        }
        publicMethod(): any{
            this.callback();
        }
}
//code...
(() => {
    function myFunction(){
        //do work
        console.log("Called myFunction");
    }
    obj = new MyOtherConstructor(myFunction);
})();

//use obj.publicMethod in code later
```

which works, but it's ugly.

Any suggestion how make this better?

Comment: What's wrong with making myFunction a private one?

Comment: You mean to make the myFunction a private one of the MyOtherConstructor?
If that's the case, I can't because I want the myFunction to be used into the anonymous function code block independently. I don't want to create the obj first and then use the function from it. I want to use the myFunction as is into that code block and create a new obj object that has the myFunction method. It will be used later in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a single object `obj`, then do not use a class. A namespace is more adapted:

```
namespace obj {
    function myFunction() {
        // ...
    }
    export var publicMethod = myFunction;
}
```

---

If you prefer to keep the class, then here is a more concise code for it:

```
class MyOtherConstructor {
    constructor(public publicMethod: () => void) {
    }
}
```