# Typescript Revealing Module Pattern

Tags: typescript

I am using The Revealing Module Pattern with JS in an angular application.

Now I am going to migrate it from Javascript to Typescript, but I have no idea how to use this pattern with TS. I have read some other post like the following, but no one of them have the return at the beginning of the function. [TypeScript code similar to Revealing Module Pattern structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275307/typescript-code-similar-to-revealing-module-pattern-structure)

```
angular.module('app.services')
.factory('justAService', justAService);

function justAService() {

return {
  a: a
};

var x = {};

function a(){....}
```

Is it possible to write the return at the top?

Thank you

Comment: Don’t use that pattern; TypeScript has actual modules. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: Putting `var x = {};` after the return also doesn’t make any sense. It will never be reached. It’s equivalent to declaring `var x;` and not initializing it.

Comment: Yes you are right. Why should a use modules instead of this pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. It's usually used to improve readability and it doesn't affect the program execution at all. Because function evaluation (definition) occur before that javascript gets executed, so when your module returns a reference to the function, it had already been defined. But it just works for functions declared this way, otherwise will be unreachable code.

Example:

```
module App{
    angular.module('app.services')
        .factory('justAService', justAService);

    function justAService() {

        return {
            a: a
        };

        function a() {

            var x = {};
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May you show me a sample? I tried it but the function is always unreachable

Comment: What exactly have you tried? The given example seems to be on this situation.

Comment: I edited my sample. The code is pretty much like the sample

Comment: As I said in my answer it just work for function declarations, using a `var x = {}` will cause unreachable code. I've updated my answer with an example.